# IllegalArgumentException on Spring RestController when using Spring security Principal object for authentication

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I try implement Spring Security on back-end and Angularjs on front-end web app work together. But when I try authenticate user via /user method I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:68) ...
```

anglarjs authenticate function :

```
 var authenticate = function(credentials, callback) {

    var headers = credentials ? {authorization : "Basic "
        + btoa(credentials.username + ":" + credentials.password)
    } : {};

    console.log("header",headers);

    $http.get('user', {headers : headers}).success(function(data) {
      if (data.name) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = true;
      } else {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      }
      callback && callback();
    }).error(function() {
      $rootScope.authenticated = false;
      callback && callback();
    });

  }
```

Spring rest controller:

```
@RestController
public class RestApiController {

@RequestMapping("/user")
  public Principal user(Principal user) {
    return user;
  }
...
```

Security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .httpBasic()
  .and()
    .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/index.jsp", "/resources/**","/").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
      .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
      .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());;
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
      HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
      repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
      return repository;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses a set `HttpMessageConverts` to serialize/deserialize the request/response in suitable format ie. JSON/HTML etc. With your implementation It seems that you don't have proper message converters which can serialize your `principal` object in response body. To resolve this you need to include jackson-mapper-asl*.jar and jackson-databind*.jar in your classpath